# Can anyone please explain how isPossible() function runs in the following problem, and how recursion works in a loop

Tags: recursion, backtracking

```
class Solution {
public:
    bool isPossible(string &number,int i,int k,int sum){
        if(i==number.size()) return sum==k;
        
        int num = 0;
        for(int ind=i;ind<number.size();ind++){
            num = num*10+number[ind]-'0';
            if(isPossible(number,ind+1,k,sum+num)){
                return true;
            }
        }
```

I am struggling in maintaining the recursive tree for the above isPossible() function.

Comment: "Struggling" how, exactly?  What is the specific problem you are observing?  Have you stepped through the code with a debugger to observe its runtime behavior?  When you do that, which specific operation isn't doing what you expect?

Comment: Do not tag `dsa`.  Did you read the tag carefully before you applied it?  Does your question involve Digital Signature Algorithm?

Comment: This is not a precise question. Do you need explanation of what each keyword means? What `public` means? What `&` means? What `sum==k` does? Which part of recursion is not clear? The arguments passed? The value returned? If so, what you have done to debug and inspect? You'll have to be a lot more specific.